# Selecting all rows in the oldest record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named Order-

this gives me just the 1 column -

```
 select min(OrderDate) from "order"
```

However I would like to view all the columns for that record.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT *
 from [order]
 WHERE OrderDate = (SELECT min(OrderDate) from [order])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` sand `top`:

```
select top 1 o.*
from orders o
order by orderdate asc;
```

EDIT:

If you want duplicates, use `with ties`:

```
select top 1 with ties o.*
from orders o
order by orderdate asc;
```

Comment: This will only return top 1 row, what if there are multiple rows with `OrderDate  = min(OrderDate)`

Comment: @M.Ali . . . The question is phrased in the singular:  "all the columns for that record".  In any case, it is easy enough to use `with ties` to get all rows with the same values.

Answer (score 1):

While [M. Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494544/2266979) is accurate, depending on the size of the table and the index configuration, it might result in poor performance. It requires two reads through the table.

On SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use window functions and limit the plan to a single read through the table. For very small data sets, the query cost is actually higher, but the number of reads is halved. For large data sets, that should result in significantly superior performance.

Code example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Populate Test Data

DECLARE @Orders TABLE (OrderNum int IDENTITY, OrderDate datetime);
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-04');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-04');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-04');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-05');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-05');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-06');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-07');
INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES ('2015-04-07');

-- Run Tests

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

PRINT 'Full Table';
SELECT * FROM @Orders;

PRINT 'Results using MIN';
SELECT      *
FROM        @Orders
WHERE       OrderDate = (SELECT min(OrderDate) FROM @Orders);

PRINT 'Results using RANK';
WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS OrderDateRank
    FROM        @Orders
)
SELECT      *
FROM        BaseData
WHERE       OrderDateRank = 1;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Query costs:

MIN:
0.0065718

RANK:
0.014645

Statistics:

```
Full Table
Table '#1E0C7C2B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Results using MIN
Table '#1E0C7C2B'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Results using RANK
Table '#1E0C7C2B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```